# Beginner C++ - Explaining Class Definition

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

I'm a beginner in C++ and need some help understanding the very basics. This is my class definition:

```
template <class T>
    class List;
template <class T >
    class Node {
    friend class List<T>;
private:
    Node *prev, *next;
public:
    T data;
    Node() :prev(), next() {}
    Node * Prev();
    Node * Next();
    Node * InsertAfter(List<T> * list, const T& data);
    Node * InsertBefore(List<T> * list, const T& data);
};
```

I'm not entereily sure how to format my Constructor

```
    Node() :prev(), next() {}
```

And this code segment over here:

```
    Node * InsertAfter(List<T> * list, const T& data);
    Node * InsertBefore(List<T> * list, const T& data);
```

Does that mean that the method should return a node?

Thanks

Comment: _Does that mean that the method should return a node_ - yes, but it should have documentation which node it returns. It could return the new node, or it could return itself (`this`).

Comment: Okay but how would the constructor method look like using Node() : prev(), next() {}

Comment: *Does that mean that the method should return a node?* **No!** The method should return a pointer to a `Node`. There's a big difference, and it's important when learning the basics to be aware of the difference between.

Comment: So is Node * Prev(); just similar to java getNode or something like that?

Answer (score 1):

I would have written overrided default constructor like below:

```
Node() 
 : prev(nullptr)
 , next(nullptr) 
 {
 }
```

The default constructor should always contain routines to initialize the data members to their zeroed values or un-initialized values(`enum` values having name `UNKNOWN` or `INVALID`). In case any of your objects remains uninitialized, zeroing causes the segment fault if someone tries to perform any operation on uninitialized objects. Which is easy to debug than a memory corruption if we leave empty constructor body.